# searching why memory is not being allocated

Tags: c++

I Read all about the reasons for this **error(SIGABRT)** -> made this program using arrays and that gave me SIGSEGV. Please show me where have I asked for some memory which compiler cannot allocate or narrow it down to exact problem and where it resides??
Constraints are described below, and I've used `long long int`

1. 1 ≤ T ≤ 100
2. 1 ≤ N, K ≤ 100,000
3. 1 ≤ sum of K over all test cases ≤ 100,000
4. 1 ≤ Ai, Di ≤ 1,000,000 for each valid i
5. 1 ≤ Bi ≤ C for each valid i
6. Bi+1 < Bi for each valid i

   ```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>
   using namespace std;
   typedef long long int ll;


   int main() {
   ll T;
   cin>>T;

   while(T--){

       ll N,K;
       cin>>N>>K;

       vector<ll> A(N,0);
       vector<ll> D(N,0);
       vector<ll> B(N,0);

       for(ll i=0; i<N ; i++){             // O(N)
           cin>>A[i];
       }

       for(ll i=0; i<N ; i++){             // O(N)
           cin>>D[i];
       }

       for(ll i=0; i<K ; i++){             // O(K)
           cin>>B[i];
       }

       ll vect_size=0;

       for(ll i=0; i<N ; i++)              // O(N)
           vect_size += D[i] ;

       //cout<<vect_size<<endl;

       vector<ll> cards(vect_size,0);
       ll sum=0;


       for(ll i=0; i<N ; i++){

           for(ll j=0; j<D[i] ; j++){

               cards[ sum+j ] = A[i] ;
           }
           sum+=D[i];
       }


      //sort(cards, cards+vect_size );                    // O(N.logN)  ::  N = vect_size
      sort(cards.begin(), cards.end());

       //----------------------game-begins-now-----------------------------------------



       ll left_lim=0;
       ll right_lim=vect_size-1;
       ll cur_size=vect_size;

       for(ll i=0; i<K; i++){

           if( i%2==0 ){

                   left_lim += cur_size-B[i] ;
                   cur_size  = B[i];

           }
           else{

                   right_lim -= cur_size-B[i];
                   cur_size  = B[i];
           }            




       }

       sum=0;



       for(ll i=left_lim; i<=right_lim; i++)
               sum += cards[i];

       cout<<sum<<"\n";


   }


   return 0;
   ```

   }

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Also please avoid creating "shortcuts" of common types using `typedef`, it makes the code harder to read and understand.

Comment: Much more related to your problem, please take some time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Being able to debug your programs is a required skill for any programmer on any level.

Comment: You probably just ran out of memory due to an infinite loop, or due to inefficient handling of a very large input. Those sites tend to have good test cases, so they found a bug in your code, but asking us defeats the purpose of learning or competing.

Comment: A possible problem is that you use `N` as the size for `B`, but use `K` as the limit for `B[i]`.

Comment: thanks man, really needed such a thing. If there a tutorial available somewhere, I am sure it would be of great help to us newbies.

Comment: Just looking at the limits: if `D[i]` is 1,000,000 for all `i`, and `N` is 100,000, `vect_size` will be one hundred billion. I suspect you need a cleverer algorithm.

Comment: @Bo Persson, i did that using K now, still it's the same, but yeah thanks I'll change that now.

Comment: @molbdnilo do you think making a multimap  of <Ai,Di> will improve complexity?? current time complexity is O(N.logN) with N = vect_size

Comment: You just need a sorted sequence of pairs of (Ai, Di). If you played this in the real world, you would most likely keep piles of similar-valued cards rather than spreading them all out and counting them. Do that in the program.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what is the problem you are having (e.g., which line throws the error), but this can get you started:

1. Use `std::vector<ll>::max_size()` to get the maximum allowable size.
   This is possibly `2^30-1`.
   Check if you are exceeding that.
2. If `N < vect_size`, line `cards[ sum+j ] = A[i]` is a problem.
3. `vect_size` can be up to `LONG_MAX * LONG_MAX` (see [climits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)).
   `LONG_MAX` is possibly `2^31-1` or greater, so `LONG_MAX * LONG_MAX` may be approx. `2^62`, which conceivably exceeds the limit in point 1.
   This is probably not what you want.
4. Depending on the specific contents of your `vector`s, the only other possibly problematic line is `sum += cards[i]`.